# Maven - Could not copy webapp sources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have problem with maven:

my error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project :
     Could not copy webapp sources [C:\Users\...]: C:\Users\... access denied-> [Help 1]
        [ERROR]
```

I got this error all the time. Earlier I restarted eclipse and everything was OK, but now it doesn't work. How to fix it?

EDIT:
I did nothing and now maven clean and build works correctly. Is it possible that some threads create that error  ?

Comment: do not have the privilege to access the webapp sources directory?

Comment: Yes, to each file.

Comment: @lulyon how to check this privileges  ?

Comment: it appears that you are on windows, so I recommend windows cmd as the below answer suggests. Open for more discussion.

Comment: I check with this command and each person have (0I)(CI)F privileges. @lulyon

Comment: yes, so is the example suggests. I'll add example that grant privileges to supposed user later.

Comment: I mislead in the above comment. the example has grant privilege for the supposed user.

Comment: I solve this problem, @lulyon. I  create Ext files on other jar file, but i did not notice that this jar required another source files, when maven clean files he misses deleting missing files but maven can't miss copy files to build new war,  so there was my mistake. Thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Cacls](https://technet.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/bb490872.aspx)** command under Windows cmd, might solve your problem.

> Cacls D:\desktop /G user:F : acquire privilege

For more example: [cacls-command-examples](http://www.windows-commandline.com/cacls-command-examples/).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and in my case it had nothing to do with ACL. One of the files was marked as read only and maven refused to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

I used invalidated cache/Restart from IntelliJ IDEA and it worked.